# Selecting lists where all are prime

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
    t={{7, 13, 19}, {13, 25, 37}, {19, 37, 55}, {25, 49, 73}, {31, 61, 91}, {37, 73, 109}}
```

I want to select those lists where all three numbers are primes, so I should get

```
{{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}}
```

I am looking for some equivalent of

```
Select[PrimeQ] /@ t
Cases[___?PrimeQ] /@ t
Pick[#, PrimeQ@#] &@ t
```

But these just give me all primes in all sublists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html):

```
Select[t, AllTrue[PrimeQ]]
(* {{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}} *)
```

Alternatively, you should specify the pattern you actually want in `Cases`:

```
Cases[t, {___?PrimeQ}]
(* {{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}} *)
```

If for some reason you really want a function you can `Map` over the list to do what you want, you'll need to use `Replace` in concert with the special symbol [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html):

```
Map[Replace[Except[{___?PrimeQ}] -> Nothing], t]
(* {{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[t, And @@@ PrimeQ @ t]
```

> ```
> {{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Either of these takes advantage of the fact that `PrimeQ` automatically threads over lists:

```
Select[t, Apply[And]@*PrimeQ]
Select[t, And @@ PrimeQ[#] &]

(* Out: {7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I see there are alrready lots of good answers, but my thought was to turn the True and False of the PrimeQ command to 1 and 0, then mutliply:

```
Extract[t, Position[Times @@@ Boole[PrimeQ[t]], 1]]

{{7, 13, 19}, {37, 73, 109}}
```